# How do I fix my docker-compose.yml I get a rabbitmq.config is a directory error?

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, docker-compose

I have the following lines in my docker-compose.yml

```
rabbit:
   volumes:
     - ./enabled_plugins:/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins
     - ./config/definitions.json:/opt/definitions.json:ro
     - ./config/rabbitmq.config:/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config:ro
```

But for the rabbitmq.config when I start up it says

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 386: /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config: Is a directory
```

Any idea what is wrong here in my volume declarations???

Comment: What I want to do is adding some exchanges when I startup my rabbitmq server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mounting files as directories.

The simplified solution is to mount the parent directory of the files you are mounting into the container, into the directories you want them to.

```
rabbit:
   volumes:
     - .:/etc/rabbitmq
     - ./config:/opt:ro
     - ./config:/etc/rabbitmq:ro
```

But notice you are mounting into `/opt`, and you would want to avoid it, so put all the config files into `config` on your host and mount them explicitly into directories:

```
rabbit:
   volumes:
     - ./config:/etc/rabbitmq
     - ./config:/opt/rabbitmq:ro
```

Notice you need to update `rabbitmq.config` to new location of `definition.json`

Comment: Thanks that was it. Although in some code examples they set explicitly the files as volumes. Anyway that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the `./config/rabbitmq.config` in your current directory is actually a directory instead of a config file that `docker-entrypoint.sh` is expecting.

Comment: No it is not. When I do `file ./config/rabbitmq.config` I get ASCII text.

Comment: That's strange and I can't reproduce what you experienced. Then I would suggest you copy the accurate directory structure to another directory, ensure `./config/rabbitmq.config` is the configure file you want and `docker-compose up` the same `docker-compose.yml` to verify.